# Is there a way to detect or change the EOL format from windows to linux in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, eol

My application cannot read windows format EOL files, is there's a way I can detect the format of a files? or change the EOL to the linux format?
I would like to be able to display a error message if the format is not linux.
I know that windows format EOL is CRLF and linux is LF.

Comment: You can try to do it manually, checking for `'\r'` symbol as well as `'\n'`.

Comment: How are you reading the file?  In what mode?

Answer (score 1):

Just:

- open file in binary mode
- find first '\n' byte
- check if byte before found one equals '\r'

If you ask if there is such functionality in standard library, I answer - there isn't.

Comment: I will try that.